# Why are we not helping Syria?

Tags: dhabihah, human-rights, ethics

I know this is not the place for such questions. I just know there are many Muslim users here and moreover many humans here. So many countries with so many humans are not doing anything to help a small country? It has been years. Many countries call themselves powerful but still don't take a step to help Syria. Why can't we help them? Imagine how powerful we are if we join each other and stop it. How will we face Allah when we will be asked what did we do to stop it? When will we help them? Why don't we help them?

Comment: These kinds fo question don't fit for the stack exchange network consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn what is on and off-topic here

Comment: This might make an interesting topic of discussion in [chat], but as you say it is not the sort of question we can handle on the main site here.

Comment: @goldPseudo do I have the privileges to create a chat room?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13088/islamic-chat it is frozen

Comment: Try [Jaami'at StackExchange al-Islamyya](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/jaamiat-stackexchange-al-islamyya) instead.  (Also, I found the [Vox Explainer on Syria](https://www.vox.com/2017/4/8/15218782/syria-trump-bomb-assad-explainer) helpful.)